# Is it ok to ask for 2 weeks to prepare for a tech interview?

Tags: interviewing, tech-industry

I've a lot on my plate currently and would like to schedule interviews in 2 weeks. Is this an unreasonable amount of time to ask for?

Comment: To *prepare* or simply to schedule an interview because your calendar is packed? There's a big difference between the two. Are you interviewing / planning to interview for specific openings or do you have an in-demand profile that companies would be interested in regardless of vacancies (e.g. consulting)?

Comment: If you get the interview go to the interview. Don't stall. Seriously.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how fast they want to move. If they have an immediate need and want to hire someone quickly, there's a good chance they'll settle on a candidate while you're still preparing. As Joe Strazzere mentioned, it could also have a negative impact on how you're perceived. A candidate who really wants the job may be more willing to adjust their schedule to accommodate the interview.

It's great that you want to take time to make sure you're adequately prepared for what they might throw at you, however a candidate who doesn't need time to prepare may be perceived by some to be better qualified. So, if you decide to go this route, rather than saying you need time to prepare, I would simply say that your schedule is very busy and you would prefer to postpone if possible.

Answer (score 2):

If I were interviewing you, I would not like this. It's not a full-blown red flag, but I don't like the smell of it.

I don't throw out gotcha questions; nor do I care about obscure language features. I want to get a good feel for what you are capable of now, day to day - ***NOT*** what you can cram for in a fortnight and then promptly forget after the interview.

I am looking for someone who is comfortable with our development methods, not necessarily a superstar, and someone who is a good fit for the team. I can also overlook lack project specific knoweldge, if it is niche, so long as you appear trainable. I know what Joel, etc, say about only hiring A people, but they don't have to accept the realities that most of us do. Just be competent and confident, and I will hire you; forget the trivia.